# Jest - react native - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, jestjs, module

I want to use Unit test with react native / expo. When I start them with `npm test` I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```js
import { getRandomBase64String } from 'react-native-get-random-values'
```

I already add this problems but skip it by using Mock. There I can't skip it with Mock because this function is the center of my function.

What i tried:

```json
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!react-native-crypto)",
    "/node_modules/(?!react-native-randombytes)"
],
"preset": "ts-jest",
"transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
}
```

Modifications of my `babel.config.json` use `require` instead add `type="module"`.

My current `package.json`:

```json
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js"
  }
},
```

My current `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
   api.cache(true);
   return {
       presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
   };
};
```